# De passiva voce cum verbis quae casum dativum postulant

Tags: passive-voice, case

Quaestio mihi fuit dum scribebam sententiam quandam. Si vero verbum (quod deponens non est) postulat casum dativum (e.g., *ignoscere*), quomodo rectius scribitur in passiva voce?

Exempli gratia,

> Nemo ignoscetur nisi contritus

vs.

> Nemini ignoscetur nisi contrito

[In hoc carmine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaudeamus_igitur) invenitur "nemini parcetur". Etiam in [aliis locis](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=kIZaAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA187&lpg=PA187&dq=%22nemini+ignoscitur%22&source=bl&ots=aZP67zOEXk&sig=ACfU3U25R7qiMMS_tOKYupS_V2kwq5py0Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiOif_pjNv2AhU8m5UCHbvwCbsQ6AF6BAgFEAM#v=onepage&q=%22nemini%20ignoscitur%22&f=false) inveni formam `v. (pass) + dat.`, sed miror sententiae subiectum non esse in casu nominativo.

Comment: A&G 372: "Intransitive verbs that govern the dative are used _impersonally_ in the passive (§ 208.d). The dative is retained (cf. § 365) (...). Note: In poetry the personal construction is sometimes found: _Cūr invideor_? (Hor. A. P. 56)". Cf. the more usual impersonal passive construction: _cur invidetur mihi_?" (https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0001%3Asmythp%3D372 ).

Comment: Aliqua ēmendābō: nōn *quaestiō mihi fuit* "I had an investigation, inquiry" sed *dubium mihi fuit, dubitābam, mē interrogābam, mīrātus sum* etc. Nōn *sī vērō* "but if" sed *sī rē vērā, sī vērum est.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quā dē causā ōrātiōnis subjectum in nōminātīvō nōn pōnātur ex hīs liquēbit:

- *Jūlia* Mārcō ***rosam** dat = **rosa*** Mārcō *ā Jūliā datur !=* Mārcus *ā Jūliā datur*
- *Jūlia* Mārcō ***omnia** ignōscit = **omnia*** Mārcō *ā Jūliā ignōscuntur !=* Mārcus *ā Jūliā ignōscitur*

Ut hinc appāret, ōrātiō passīva fit cum **objectum (rēctum)** subjectī vice pōnitur. Objectum vērō **oblīcum** passīvam ōrātiōnem facere nōn potest; ubi ita facere vidētur (*ego invideor*), rē vērā ex [*mē invident*](https://latin.packhum.org/loc/474/49/56/1478-1493#56) conversum est, nōn *mihi.*

In *nēminī ignōscētur* autem nūllum subjectum appāret quia et in *alicui ignōscere* nūllum objectum: scīlicet verbum **intrānsītīvum** est quod passīvum impersōnāliter facit.